# ReferenceError: ComponentType is not defined Как исправить?

Tags: javascript, discord

```
    data: new SlashCommandBuilder()
        .setName('control')
        .setDescription('Управление пользователем')
        .addUserOption(option =>
            option
                .setName('target')
                .setDescription('Пользователь, кем вы хотите управлять')
                .setRequired(true))
        .setDefaultMemberPermissions(PermissionFlagsBits.BanMembers, PermissionFlagsBits.KickMembers)
        .setDMPermission(false),
        async execute(interaction) {
            const member = await interaction.guild.members.fetch(interaction.options.getUser("target").id);


            const embed1 = new EmbedBuilder()
            .setTitle("Управление пользователя")
            .setColor(0x08f300)
            .addFields(
                { name: 'Участник', value: `<@${member.user.id}>`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Дата регистрации', value: `<t:${Math.round(member.user.createdTimestamp / 1000)}>`, inline: true },
                { name: 'Присоединился к серверу', value: `<t:${Math.round(member.joinedAt / 1000)}>`, inline: true },
            )
            const row = new ActionRowBuilder()
            .addComponents(
                new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('ban')
                    .setLabel('Забанить')
                    .setEmoji(``)
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger),
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('unban')
                    .setLabel('Разбанить')
                    .setEmoji(``)
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('mute')
                    .setLabel('Мут')
                    .setEmoji(``)
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Danger),
                    new ButtonBuilder()
                    .setCustomId('unmute')
                    .setLabel('Размут')
                    .setEmoji(``)
                    .setStyle(ButtonStyle.Success),
                );
                    await interaction.reply({ components: [row], embeds: [embed1] });
                    const message = await interaction.fetchReply();
                    const collector = message.createMessageComponentCollector({ componentType: ComponentType.Button, time: 15000, filter: i => i.user.id === interaction.member.id });
                    collector.on("collect", i => { 
                        if (i.customId === "ban") { 
                            const member = interaction.options.getMember("target");
                            const role = interaction.guild.roles.cache.get("1075876710832152616");
                            member.roles.add(role);
                        }
                    })}};
```

Ошибка
`Error executing control ReferenceError: ComponentType is not defined`

Comment: ComponentType undefined, скорее всего импорта нет или корявый

Comment: ComponentType не определен.

Попробуй добавить import { SlashCommandBuilder, ButtonStyle, ComponentType } from '@discordjs/builders'; в начале файла, чтобы импортировать ComponentType.

Также глянь, что  установлены все необходимые зависимости, включая @discordjs/builders.